# Set concatenated string as a application_name

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-13

I'm trying to set application_name with some concatenated string as shown below in the example:

**Example**:

```
do
$$
declare var1 text := 'Text1';
        var2 text := 'Text2';
        result text;
begin
    set application_name = var1||'-'||var2;
    
    select application_name into result 
    from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid();

    raise info '%',result;
end;
$$;
```

But getting an error:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "||"   Position: 116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `format` to concatenate the string and then `execute` it, e.g.

```
do
$$
declare var1 text := 'Text1';
        var2 text := 'Text2';
        result text;
begin    
    execute format('set application_name=%s',quote_ident(var1||'-'||var2));
    select application_name into result 
    from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid();    
    raise info '%',result;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: The alternative is to use the `set_config()` function;